# How to pass a value to a form for unittest?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to write test for my code and pass a value to a form how can i do that? I have two form in my code and this value should pass just to one of them.

my unittest:

```
def test_user_has_project(self):
    resp = self.client.post('/register/', NEW_USER)
    self.assertRedirects(resp, '/register/confirm/')
    confirmation_code = self.client.session['confirm_code']
    resp = self.client.post('/register/confirm/',
                            {'confirm_code':confirmation_code})
```

but this code pass confirmation code to both forms.

my views:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.RegistrationConfirmForm(request.POST)
    if (form.is_valid() and
        form.cleaned_data['confirm_code'] == request.session['confirm_code']):
            # Register the user in the backend
            form = forms.RegistrationForm(request.session['registering_user'])
```

sorry. I'm a beginner in both coding and asking question!